# refreshable listview using jazzy listview android

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, jazzylistview

I already implemented `PullToRefreshListView` and worked fine ,
and I already implemented `JazzylistView` and worked fine , but I also want to implement `JazzylistView` with `PullToRefresh ListView`. Is this possible?

Anyone know this answer , please help me?